# How to append directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue where the the nesting of appended directives is not working correctly. query-row is a directive (with an HTML template) and I want to have the following DOM structure

Desired Outcome

```
<query-row></query-row>
<query-row></query-row>
<query-row></query-row>
etc...
```

But what I get is this. Also see screenshot

```
<query-row>
   <query-row></query-row>
   <query-row></query-row>
   etc...
</query-row>
```

[image]

Javascript code. As you can see here, in the controller I'm creating an element called query-row and then I'm appending it to the prior query-row...but here is where my logic is faulty because it's not appending, but rather nesting in the first query-row.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('queryBuilderCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.add = function() {
      var queryRow = angular.element(document.createElement('query-row'))
      $compile(queryRow)($scope)
      angular.element('query-row').append(queryRow)
    }
  }])
  .directive('queryBuilder', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'queryBuilderTemplate.html',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      }
    }
  }).directive('queryRow', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'queryRowTemplate.html',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      }
    }
  });
```

Here is a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1WAgBCEbyk7Tz3fLKnnW

Comment: .append` is what adding DOM inside, you should use `.after()`/`.before()`..but also doing DOM manipulation from the controller would be considered as bad pattern..

Comment: Regarding best practices, you shouldn't be using .append for adding HTML to your page. Ideally you would be managing your child views in a repeater like ng-repeat or some other directive, then you can just have a $scope variable which contains data to inject into each looped element properly. Or in this case, your queryBuilder should contain a repeater which will manage the query-rows

Comment: @SoluableNonagon can you explain this in an example? I'm not really liking the .append solution either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## answer to the question

It appears that the problem is here:

```
 angular.element('query-row').append(queryRow)
```

You probably meant:

```
angular.element('query-row').last().after(queryRow)
```

**edit** - modified to place queryRow element inside form element per @PierreDuc's comment.  This finds the last `<query-row>` element and then append the newly created `queryRow` element after it.

## better solution

But honestly this is very much **not** how I'd recommend doing this.  You are having a view controller (`queryBuilderCtrl`) handle DOM manipulation.  In only extreme cases should you do this.  You should probably set up a array model object in your `queryBuilderCtrl` and its template utilizes `ng-repeat` to handle the DOM creation/destroying.

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/k4PUNfeRdeGsxEdruEZi?p=preview

Comment: that will place it outside the form. I believe it should be `angular.element('query-row').last().after(queryRow)`

Comment: @jusopi, no, I want all the rows placed inside of the form, which is a part of query-builder. There can be multiple query-rows inside query-builder

Comment: use @PierreDuc's suggestion then, I will update the answer

Comment: @PierreDuc - that works, can you please explain the answer?

Comment: @jusopi - can you give an example of an alternative solution? one perhaps that doesn't involve modifying DOM in controller

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with a fork of your plunker.

Comment: also I showed how you could do the adding in two ways... one is via an event bus, the other using `ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end` to keep the `<query-row>` cleaner

Comment: @jusopi please check my answer

Comment: @tomepejo thank you.  I checked out your plunker.  I'm sorry but I still don't recommend that because it still delegates DOM manipulation to a view controller which has been explicitly stated as very non-NG on their docs: "Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation." - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.  In terms of addressing his original question, yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.element('query-row').last().after(queryRow)`

This works because it will first select all `query-row` elements. With the function `last()`, you will get the last one (obviously). With the `after(queryRow)`, you place the `queryRow` after the last `query-row` element

As @jusopi stated, DOM manipulation should however be reduced to a minimum in controllers

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/DPy8YoaGh1mAAJpFrWE7

I added new `<div>` with class `query-row-wrapper` inside of the `queryBuilderTemplate.html`, so every new compiled `query-row` is appended to this wrapper.

The resulting HTML is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Shoot for a non-`.append` solution

http://plnkr.co/edit/i4S3K4JjcTPXkTLT9eOq?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.rows = [{data: 'something'}];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.rows.push({data: 'data1'}); // whatever data goes into a row
  }


}]); 

app.directive('queryBuilder', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      rows: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'queryBuilderTemplate.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // do something here?
      console.log( scope.rows );
    }
  }
}).directive('queryRow', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      data: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'queryRowTemplate.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // process data in some way?
        console.log( scope.data )
    }
  }
});
```

queryBuilderTemplate.html

```
<div class="queryBuilder">
    <query-row ng-repeat='row in rows' data='row.data'></query-row>
</div>
```

queryRowTemplate.html

```
Test {{data}}
```